# Programming 8255 over 16f84a

Tags: pic

I am trying to write control byte of the 8255 ppi(Programmable Peripheral Interface) through 16f84a. Everything fine with Proteus but I can't write anything to 8255 on my circuit. Inputs get out from 16f84a(PORTB) and connected to the Data bus of 8255. Some said must have an delay to write 8255. I tried but didn't work. Here is a test program I wrote to get output through 8255. all ports are set to output (A,B,C). But it doesn't work.
link for proteus screen shot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQbfG.jpg

```
bsf     PORTA,3                 ; activate 8255's reset pin
            call jDelay

            bcf     PORTA,3                 ; deactivate 8255's reset pin

            movlw   b'00000001'                 ; Control byte for 8255 (B0->D7....B7->D0) /reverse of 10000000 (all set to output)
            movwf   PORTB
            movlw   b'00000011'                 ; mode 11 to write control register and also PortA.3-> 8255.WR (activate with 0 ,WR pin active-low)
            movf PORTA                          ;portA.0->8255.A0&& portA.1->8255.A1

            call    jDelay                      ; Delay to write control byte

            bsf     PORTA,2                     ; Deactive Write pin of 8255 (Active-low , 1 deactivates)

main


    movlw      B'10110110'       ; Digit value for 5
    movwf       PORTB
        movlw b'00000000'       ; mode 00 and activate WR pin
        movwf PORTA             ; write to portA so -> 8255
        call jDelay             ; Delay to write  byte
        bsf     PORTA,2         ; Deactivate 8255's WR pin(active-low)

        Delay                   ;endless loop
        goto Delay

        jDelay                   ; Delay loop
        Loop3               decfsz              COUNT1,1
                        goto Loop3
                            decfsz              COUNT3,1
                        goto Loop3

    return
end
```

Comment: The symptom is the input from Data bus doesnt arrive to the output ports of the 8255. I checked and tested with leds and multimeter

Comment: Do the output port pins get set correctly? (You may wish to temporarily increase the delay by a huge amount.)

Comment: yep all pins are correct 4 different guy and 4 different circuit , but the same problem.Frends faced same problem so i posted here. The delay is around 1-2 sec. And i have tried much more. But never wrote anything to 8255.

Comment: by the way I did same thing without using 8255 for previous HW and everything was fine.

Comment: Did you test with the LED disconnected?

Comment: the led is at output side. I cant get output so i cant turn on the leds. what is the point of disconnecting leds?

Comment: The point is that the LED may be pulling the output low.

Comment: nope. Still same outputs(no output) without led

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you blew the 8255. Your circuit effectively shorts the 8255's outputs to ground. You don't give the exact part number of the 8255 you are using, but they typically have a maximum output current of around 4mA *total* for all bits on a single port. There should also be a note on the datasheet that *no* current-limiting is provided and must be provided by the external circuitry. You have no current-limiting.

An LED is pretty close to a short to ground. The 8255 simply cannot drive it.

Disconnect the LED and see if the 8255's outputs still work. If not, replace the 8255 and use a proper output driver or a least a 330 ohm resistor between each port output and the LED.

Comment: I took off 1 digit 7seg display from previous HW. It worked. As you said 4 Digit 7seg display has problem. I have tried another 4digit 7seg display. Still no light.  What should I do to use 4 digit 7seg display?

Comment: You have to follow the specifications for both the display and the 8255. You may need an output driver. You may need dropping resistors. If you have a link to the spec sheet for the display you are using and give me the exact model of 8255 you are using, I can tell you the easiest way to get the job done. (Maybe one has built-in dropping resistors or current limiters? Maybe one has built in LED drivers?)

Comment: 8255AC-2 iam using and for 4 digit 7 segment display I dont know the model. But this code writes on it "JYFD056ASR-20"

Comment: Okay, your [display](http://www.optoe.com/up_files/pdf/Digit%20Display/0.56%E2%80%9D_14.20mm_%20Quadruple%20Digit%20Display.pdf) wants 20mA with a forward drop of 2V. You [8255](http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/119081/NEC/UPD8255AC-2/186/3/UPD8255AC-2.html) can only supply 2mA. You need a driver.